# How to store and manage a sql schema, with the ability to update and insert data

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, devops

I am wondering what the best way (or any way) to manage a database schema. I have a sql file with a bunch of statements like `CREATE TABLE Users { id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY ....};` which represents the schema for my database.

I have postgres installed on my dev machine however am having trouble syncing the changes I make to the schema with the local database. Currently I just run drop the entire database and run the schema file on the database.

I figure there has to be a better way I don't know about. I will also need to be able to set a database up for production when the project becomes more stabilized and obviously dropping a table in production wont work.

Suggestions?

Comment: Basically you are searching for migration tool: either migration-based(delta  scripts) or state-based. Migration based: Redgate Flyway

Comment: Lukasz is right, you are looking for a schema migration tool. Have a look at Liquibase or Flyway